# Website still blocked after hack

Tags: google, domains, web-development, security, malware

I manage a website that was hacked a few months ago (I wasn't the webmaster then), it was running on Joomla. I have manages to redo the website with custom codes (php/mysql), but it still some visitors still complain that their AV blocks them from viewing the website.

I have also cleared the former database and anything related to it, contents and the likes.

My website is [here](http://satcomng.com)

I have looked for malwares in Google Webmaster but it says there are non

Also I checked with Google Safe Browsing [image: Google Safe Browsing]

[image: Google Webmaster]

Please what could the problem be.

Comment: It opened here with no issues. Any idea where the people with the problem are located? Is that only in a certain region?

Comment: Which antivirus software are these visitors using? What message do they see? (Virus Total reports no problems with the site, so you need more information to determine the cause. https://www.virustotal.com/url/18f80e1c3241823aa91380220f896e962ee375ecc7365ee94dbc73d3c8ff068d/analysis/1353682554/ )

Comment: No problem here (Avast! AntiVirus). Also, is it only certain pages that are blocked, or the whole website? Virus makers do maintain lists of sites that are blocked and you are likely to have to submit a request to be removed from the block list.

Comment: One my friend had recovered his Joomla site after hacking : http://tinyurl.com/c84rxax . Just see if it could be of any help to you. He did not observe the issues you're facing now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

End-user malware systems often use their own databases to identify issues on sites.  Some systems use domain-wide blocks while others use page-specific blocks.

Also, I have seen a lag between de-listing at these sites and end user updates.  In some AV products, the malware signatures may be local.  If the user has not updated their AV in some time, your site could still be blocked.

First, what percentage of users are complaining?  Perhaps it is a rather small number and more likely an end-user configuration issue than problem with your site.

Second, if you can get the information find out the AV version and URL they saw the warning.

Third, you may want to consider a service like:
http://www.sucuri.net/

To scan your site.

Keep in mind that Google will only flag your site if it hits a page with malware.  If that page is now crawled, then it could list you as clean while other services list your site as suspect.